# Where are the "Replacement Patterns" (Tokens) in "Set Data Value" in Rules?

Tags: rules

Most of the actions in Rules allow you to use tokens, but seemingly the most obvious place where this would be useful, "Set a data value," does not seem to support it. Am I missing something? It seems like it would be pretty trivial to add support for this, but I can't find in the code why, for example, the "title" field in "create a new entity" supports tokens, but "Set a data value" does not. Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Drupal and Rules do you have? I'm using drupal 7 and Rules 7.x-2.6, and when I add a new Rule, I add an "Action", then "Set a data value", then you have a data selector to choose your token. I chose "node:title". On the next page, I have the possibility to put PHP code or Replacement patterns. Maybe it's because of your view type or your condition... Did you see this line "To make entity fields appear in the data selector, you may have to use the condition 'entity has field' (or 'content is of type')." ? Or maybe it's just me confusing Replacement Patterns and tokens.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of the selected target data whether tokens can be used for the value or not.

For example if the target is a simple text field (e.g. `node:title`) then the value can be specified with tokens. On the other hand, if the selected target is for example an entity (e.g. `node:field-tags:0`), then token input is not possible.

When working with formatted text, it is necessary to drill down to the `value` column of the field. E.g. for the node body, specify `node:body:value`.

Comment: It's a long text field for the target field

Comment: @NigelWaters: Could you be more specific? Perhaps provide the machine name of the target field type in question?

Comment: It's no different than a standard body field without a summary. field name is field_description set to Full HTML

Comment: @NigelWaters: Updated the answer with directions when working with formatted text.

Comment: It appears that the ability to use replacement patterns return when the text field is changed to "plain text". Using "Filtered text (user selects text format)" does not work.

Comment: @NigelWaters: You **can** use tokens in formatted / filtered text. See my updated answer (last paragraph).

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. My example of a body field is incorrect. I see I can set the value suing a body field, but not the value to a long text field on a message entity using the message module. Using the the message entity doesn't allow this. I am not sure if that is all enties or just message entities though.

Comment: OK. So the upshot is that replacement tokens are not available for "long text fields" but they are for "long text fields with summaries" (e.g. body fields). This is either a bug or a feature request for the Rules module. Thank-you znerol for your insight. It pointed me to the right direction. Bounty awarded and I will open up an issue in the Rules module issue queue.